# JQuery UI DatePicker - Can it handle multiple dates?

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker

I need to display an inline calendar that allows one to click 1 or more dates for selection. Can the JQuery UI datepicker 1.7.1 do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker - Multiple Date Selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections)

Answer (score 16):

At the moment, Datepicker in jQuery UI doesn't allow multiple dates selection.
I created an extension to that plugin that makes it possible: [MultiDatesPicker](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/)