# jQuery UI Datepicker - Multiple Date Selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Is there a way to use the jQuery UI Datepicker widget to select multiple dates?

All help is appreciated!
If its not possible to use the jquery UI datepicker then is there something similar that does?

Comment: There is a useful plugin @ http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903628/jquery-ui-datepicker-can-it-handle-multiple-dates

Comment: thanks :) this is good, although not multi date picker

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery UI DatePicker - Can it handle multiple dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/903628/jquery-ui-datepicker-can-it-handle-multiple-dates)

Answer (score 36):

I needed to do the same thing, so have written some JavaScript to enable this, using the `onSelect` and `beforeShowDay` events. It maintains its own array of selected dates, so unfortunately doesn't integrate with a textbox showing the current date, etc. I'm just using it as an inline control, and I can then query the array for the currently selected dates.
I used [this code](http://www.bewebmaster.com/280.php) as a basis.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Maintain array of dates
var dates = new Array();

function addDate(date) {
    if (jQuery.inArray(date, dates) < 0) 
        dates.push(date);
}

function removeDate(index) {
    dates.splice(index, 1);
}

// Adds a date if we don't have it yet, else remove it
function addOrRemoveDate(date) {
    var index = jQuery.inArray(date, dates);
    if (index >= 0) 
        removeDate(index);
    else 
        addDate(date);
}

// Takes a 1-digit number and inserts a zero before it
function padNumber(number) {
    var ret = new String(number);
    if (ret.length == 1) 
        ret = "0" + ret;
    return ret;
}

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            addOrRemoveDate(dateText);
        },
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var year = date.getFullYear();
            // months and days are inserted into the array in the form, e.g "01/01/2009", but here the format is "1/1/2009"
            var month = padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1);
            var day = padNumber(date.getDate());
            // This depends on the datepicker's date format
            var dateString = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

            var gotDate = jQuery.inArray(dateString, dates);
            if (gotDate >= 0) {
                // Enable date so it can be deselected. Set style to be highlighted
                return [true, "ui-state-highlight"];
            }
            // Dates not in the array are left enabled, but with no extra style
            return [true, ""];
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: This is nice! =) Do you have any non-javascript fallback?

Comment: insertZeroForDayOrMonth is not defined

Comment: replace insertZeroForDayOrMonth by padNumber. Thanks @Tevin. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Possibly the straightest non-plugin based answer

Answer (score 13):

When you modifiy it a little, it works regardless which dateFormat you have set.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
                        dateFormat: "@", // Unix timestamp
                        onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
                            addOrRemoveDate(dateText);
                        },
                        beforeShowDay: function(date){
                            var gotDate = $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate($(this).datepicker('option', 'dateFormat'), date), dates);
                            if (gotDate >= 0) {
                                return [false,"ui-state-highlight", "Event Name"];
                            }
                            return [true, ""];
                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 10):

I have now spent quite some time trying to find a good date picker that support interval ranges, and eventually found this one:

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

I believe this may be the best jquery date picker for selecting a range or multiple dates, and it is claimed to have been the base for the jQuery UI datepicker, and I see no reason to doubt that since it seems to be really powerful, and also good documented !

Answer (score 1):

The plugin developed by @dubrox is very lightweight and works almost identical to jQuery UI. My requirement was to have the ability to restrict the number of dates selected.

Intuitively, the `maxPicks` property seems to have been provided for this purpose, but it doesn't work unfortunately.

For those of you looking for this fix, here it is:

1. First up, you need to [**patch**](https://github.com/radarsh/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/tree/patch-1) `jquery.ui.multidatespicker.js`. I have submitted a [**pull request on github**](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/pull/5/files). You can use that until dubrox merges it with the master or comes up with a fix of his own.
2. Usage is really straightforward. The below code causes the date picker to not select any dates once the specified number of dates (`maxPicks`) has been already selected. If you unselect any previously selected date, it will let you select again until you reach the limit once again.

   `$("#mydatefield").multiDatesPicker({maxPicks: 3});`

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var days = [];

    $('#calendar').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yymmdd',
        showWeek: true, showOtherMonths: false, selectOtherMonths: false,
        navigationAsDateFormat: true, prevText: 'MM', nextText: 'MM',
        onSelect: function(d) {
            var i = $.inArray(d, days);

            if (i == -1)
                days.push(d);
            else
                days.splice(i, 1);
        },
        beforeShowDay: function(d) {
            return ([true, $.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('yymmdd', d), days) == -1 ? 'ui-state-free' : 'ui-state-busy']);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

NOTE: You can prefill `days` with a list of dates like `'20190101'` with a piece of code in PHP.

Add 2 lines to your CSS:

```
#calendar .ui-state-busy a {background:#e6e6e6 !important;}
#calendar .ui-state-free a {background:none !important;}
```

To get the list of days selected by the calendar in a `<form>`:

```
<div id="calendar"></div>
<form method="post">
<input type="submit" name="calendar_get" id="calendar_get" value="Validate" />
</form>
```

Add this to the `<script>`:

```
    $('#calendar_get').click(function() {
        $(this).append('<input type="hidden" name="calendar_days" value="' + days.join(',') + '" />');
    });
```

Apply `implode` on the string in `$_POST['calendar_days']` and map `strtotime` to all the formatted dates.

Answer (score 0):

Just had a requirement for this; here is the code I used. Apply it to an input as normal, I am using the class `typeof__multidatepicker`.

It maintains a list of unique dates in the owner textbox. You can also type in there, this is not validated - obviously the server needs to check the resulting list!

I tried to get it to work with the datepicker's linked textbox but failed, so it creates an invisible input for the datepicker (it doesn't seem to work with `display:none`, hence the odd styling).

It is positioned over the main input so the datepicker appears in the correct place, and is 1px in width so you can still type into the main textbox.

It's for an intranet with a fixed platform so I haven't done much cross-browser testing.

Remember to include the handler on the `body` or it works confusingly.

```
$('.typeof__multidatepicker').each(
    function()
    {
        var _this = $(this);                        

        var picker = $('<input tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute;opacity:0;width:1px" type="text"/>');

        picker.insertAfter(this)
        .position({my:'left top', at:'left top', of:this})
        .datepicker({
            beforeShow:
                function()
                {
                    _this.data('mdp-popped', true);
                },
            onClose: 
                function(dt, dpicker)
                {   
                    var date = $.datepicker.formatDate(picker.datepicker('option', 'dateFormat'), picker.datepicker('getDate'));
                    var hash = {};
                    var curr = _this.val() ? _this.val().split(/\s*,\s*/) : [];
                    var a = [];

                    $.each(curr, 
                        function() 
                        { 
                            if(this != '' && !/^\s+$/.test(this)) 
                            {   
                                a.push(this); 
                                hash[this] = true;
                            }
                        }
                    );

                    if(date && !hash[date])
                    {
                        a.push(date);

                        _this.val(a.join(', '));
                    }                                                                   

                    _this.data('mdp-popped', false);
                    _this.data('mdp-justclosed', true);
                }
        }); 

        _this.on('focus', 
            function(e) 
            {                               
                if(!_this.data('mdp-popped') && !_this.data('mdp-justclosed'))
                    _this.next().datepicker('show'); 

                _this.data('mdp-justclosed', false);
            }
        );
    }
);

$('body').on('click', function(e) { $('.typeof__multidatepicker').data('mdp-justclosed', false); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this [plugin](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/)
http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net

- Select date ranges.
- Pick multiple dates not in secuence.
- Define a maximum number of pickable dates.
- Define a range X days from where it
  is possible to select Y dates. Define unavailable dates

Answer (score 0):

use this on:

```
$('body').on('focus',".datumwaehlen", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        minDate: -20
    });
});
```