# How to disable closing of datepicker on jQuery UI Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-events

When I open a datepicker like that:

```
$("#checkindate,#checkoutdate").datepicker({
    onClose: {
       //I'd like to disable the closing
    }
);
```

I'd like to prevent the closing of the datepicker dialog depending on a condition. The ideal would be that `return false` would stop this event.

I tried modifying the source code and there is no trivial solution.

What I want to do is to be able to select the checkout date without reopening another dialog.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to pick multiple dates from one datepicker. You probably will need to do something like their date range demo:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Comment: Isn't the question about not closing the datepicker? Where did he say selecting multiple dates?

Comment: "What I want to do is to be able to select the checkout date without reopening another dialog."

Comment: Actually I'm using the date-range example already, that's why I have the problem. I could close the first and open the second very fast but I don't think it's a good solution.

Comment: Why do you need both open at once?

Comment: I don't, I want a behaviour similar to the one in the datepickers of: http://www.rourevell.com/

Comment: I would suggest looking for a datepicker lib that supports that out of the box. I don't think you can do that easily w/ jQuery UI

Comment: I could workaround this if there would be a way to disable the closing.

Comment: there's an option to show more than one month at the time if that is what you need. Check the api

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#datepicker').blur(function(){
$(this).datepicker('show')
})
```

open up http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ and copy the code on the javascript console and see what happens

Comment: not much, less in the date range example: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#date-range

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectTask = function(selectedDate, calendar) { // pretends to remain open                         
                     setTimeout(function() {
                        $(selector).datepicker('show'); // don't go away ...
                     }, 0);
                 };
// datepicker instance
$(selector).datepicker({ onSelect:selectTask, duration:0 });
```

It's an illusion of prevent closing; might reach the goal.

Answer (score 0):

After spending around a day finally got it,

```
$( "#selector" ).datepicker({
        onSelect: function ( dateText, inst ) {
             this._updateDatepicker(inst);
         }
});
```

For all code, [click here](http://bhupendra-kanojiya.blogspot.in/2013/04/time-range-jquery-date-picker.html).

Comment: Crashes on jquery UI 1.10.3 for me

Answer (score 0):

In this question: [jQuery UI Datepicker - Multiple Date Selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections) the accepted answer explains how to implement the multiple date selection in one datepicker.

To prevent the datepicker closing after the selection of a date, you can put this in the **onClose** option:

```
$(this).data('datepicker').inline = false;
```

And add this in **onSelect** option:

```
$(this).data('datepicker').inline = true;
```