# jQuery Multiple dates picker not working if only allowing displaying days in textfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I want to allow users to pick multiple dates using "Multiple Dates Picker v1.5.2 for jQuery UI".

Since the valid range for each textfield is 1 month and the textfiels are not very long, I want to display only days when the user picks dates.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/neo3000ultra/Damxz/

The problem is when i try to define it like follows,

```
    $('#day_only').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat:"dd"
    });
```

The date picker will either stop working or only displaying a single day in the textfield, while any other `dateFormat` seems working fine.

Can anyone please help me out with this? Thanks!

Comment: This post might help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/1452066/778687

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an older post, but I ran into this with `.multiDatesPicker()` recently and it would have helped if I had known this information sooner.

`multiDatesPicker` is built on top of `ui.datepicker()`.  The closest dateFormat you can use is "mm-dd" or "mmdd" otherwise you will see "Invalid Date" errors.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use date & month for multiple calender. you can change your jquery function to like this,

```
var dates = $( "#day_only, #day_n_month" ).datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            dateFormat:'mm-dd',
            onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
                var option = this.id == "day_only" ? "minDate" : "maxDate",
                    instance = $( this ).data( "datepicker" ),
                    date = $.datepicker.parseDate(
                        instance.settings.dateFormat ||
                        $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat,
                        selectedDate, instance.settings );
                dates.not( this ).datepicker( "option", option, date );
            }
        });
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer! but it doesn't seem allow multiple dates to be picked and displayed in the textfields, it also doesn't get rid of the months.