# p:calender multiple date selection

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to achieve multiple selection of dates functionality with p:calender(primefaces 3.3),
in this way.

```
<p:calendar  id="cal" showButtonPanel="true"  mode="inline"
    value="#{bean.dates}" selection="multiple"/>
```

In Backing bean I have taken dates as a array in this way:

```
private Date[] dates;
public Date[] getDates() {
    return dates;
}

public void setDates(Date[] dates) {
    this.dates = dates;

}
```

But still didnt able to select multiple dates.

As per this blog http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=391 it works.

I tried to implement in same way .but did'nt worked.
Why is it so?

Answer (score 2):

The Blog post you have read is very outdated , in that time the calendar of primefaces was relying in YUI , while now its based on Jquery UI datepicker (which does not support the multi selection)

SO you can't achieve multiple date selection with primefaces current calendar , but you can Google a bit and find other jquery based alternatives,

for example [jQuery UI Datepicker - Multiple Date Selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections)

Answer (score 1):

No default functionnality but here is a solutionusing 2 inline calendars

```
<p:commandButton id="test" type="button"/>                                  
<p:overlayPanel for="test">
    <p:outputLabel styleClass="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive">
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                <p:calendar id="start" value="#{myModel.start}" navigator="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="inline">
                    <p:ajax event="dateSelect" update="end"/>
                </p:calendar>       
            </div>
            <div class="ui-grid-col-6">
                <p:calendar id="end" value="#{myModel.end}" navigator="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" mode="inline" mindate="#{myModel.start}"/>        
            </div>
        </div>
    </p:outputLabel>                                    
</p:overlayPanel>
```