# jquery date picker for multiple date

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

Through jquery datepicker we can select multiple dates at one time or not?If yes how we can and if not so how can i select multiple date in jquery calender.
and also

http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net is free or not and working good or not?

Comment: I think that this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections, is might that you are looking for.

Comment: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/  .this is free or not?

Comment: You you want to select a continuos range of dates you can use [Jquery UI Daterangepicker](http://tamble.github.io/jquery-ui-daterangepicker/)

Comment: i want to select specific dates not continous

Answer (score 1):

What you want is [datepainter](https://github.com/tlaitinen/datepainter). Another option is  [arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker](https://github.com/arca-computing/MultipleDatePicker), angular based.

Comment: these are free or not

Comment: i want to select specific date

Comment: This free, just download from github repos in the links

Comment: just found this old topic, I created the multiple date picker, it's angular based, open source and free ;)