# choose multiple dates in date input in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

I have an input div of month and week type. That looks like this:

**HTML Code:**

```
    <input style="background-color:#efeff0;color:#800d7e;"   value="2015-W16" type="week" id="week_year">
    <input style="background-color:#efeff0;color:#800d7e;"   value="2015-12" type="month" id="bdaymonth">
```

**Picture:**

[image]
[image]

What I want to do is to select multiple days in the month input and the week input.

Somebody know how to do this. Because I am not finding anything useful on the web.

Comment: try with multidatepicker http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery UI Datepicker - Multiple Date Selections](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections)

Comment: There is no HTML options, like: multiple="true"?