# How to select the multiple date in datetimepicker using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I need to select multiple  date in datetimepicker using Jquery.

I have the following code for select datetimepicker ,

```
$("#from_date").datetimepicker({
  minView: 2,
  format: 'Y-m-d'
});
```

Output will be,
  20-03-2015,27-03-2015,30-03-2015 in one datetimepicker

I need to select more than one date . How can I achieve this. Please help me.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple date ? did you mean multiple datetime picker or in one datepicker but multiple date selection?

Comment: I think there already is an answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections

Comment: No , I need to select more than one date  Example 20-03-2015,27-03-2015,30-03-2015 in one datetimepicker

Answer (score 1):

You need to import [ui.multidatespicker.js](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js) in your code then write following code

```
$( "#from_date").multiDatesPicker();
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3t4j9/368/)**

Comment: TypeError: $.ui is undefined

Comment: Can you post your code as jsfiddle ? May be your `jQuery` is conflict.

Comment: $.multiDatesPicker.version = $.ui.multiDatesPicker.version;

Comment: Write `$.noConflict();` when your script initialize to resolve confliction with jQuery.