# Allowing user to select dates for availability

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, datepicker

I'm trying to make a web application that allows the user to pick the days they want off in the future.

```
<div class="content">
 <center><h2>Availability</h2></center>
  <form id="form2" action="/upload/availability" method="post" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
     <label for="sel1">Select Name:</label>
     <select id="sel1" class="form-control">
     <option></option>
     <option>Employee 1</option>
     <option>Employee 2</option>
     <option>Employee 3</option>
     ...
```

Basically, I am trying to allow the user to pick their name in the select box.  Under that, I would like to have a calendar api where the user can then select day(s) in the future that they would need off, and then they can have a 'submit' button under that calendar which would post their name along with date(s) selected to the server.

I am familiar with some datepickers that allow user to choose one date, but I want to allow them to choose many dates.

I was wondering if there are any recommendations on how I could achieve this, any calendar APIs or what not that would serve the purpose. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections

Answer (score -1):

You can use [multidatespickr](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/). It will allow you to pick more than one date.