# Get multiple datetimes using JQuery datetimepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquerydatetimepicker

Configured the [datetimepicker](https://plugins.jquery.com/datetimepicker/) for an order_date input field that works fine.

```
$('#order_date').datetimepicker({
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      timeFormat: 'HH:mm:ss',
      showSecond: false,
      stepMinute: 15 
 });
```

The requirement is to pick multiple datetimes so that same order is created for multiple order_dates. What is the proper way to do this? Is it possible using a [select2](https://select2.github.io/examples.html) multi-select dropdown?

Comment: maybe look this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections

Comment: The above solution is for date pickers only. I need one for datetime picker.