# I am new to date picker. My requirement is to provide day picker from 1 to 31.

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i searched about jquery datepicker but it provides date with months.
All i want is multiple day picker from 1 to 31.
example if user selects 1,5,14 i should get date = 1,5,14 in javascript variable.

Any simple example will be of great help thanks.

Comment: This Question is already answered: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections) 
Maybe this helps you out

Comment: Can you share the code that you have already tried so we can help improve it?

Comment: Pick a month with 31 days and hide the month name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker({
    dateFormat: "d-m-y",
});

$("#getDates").click(function(e){
    var days;
    var selectedDates = $('#mdp-demo').multiDatesPicker("getDates");
    for(i in selectedDates){
        if(days)
        days += ","+selectedDates[i].split("-",1);
        else
           days = selectedDates[i].split("-",1);
    }
    alert(days);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/pepper-grinder/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/master/jquery-ui.multidatespicker.js"></script>

<div id="mdp-demo"></div>
<button id="getDates">
  Get Dates
</button>
```

Try MultiDatesPicker, may be it can help you.

[MultiDatesPicker](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#demo-simple)

Comment: i saw jquery multi date picker. But was unable to change things according to  my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Try below example of multidatespicker.

[multi dates picker example](http://multipledatepicker-site.orionhub.org:8000/MultipleDatepicker/MultipleDatePicker.html).

It may help you to achieve your requirements.