# primefaces JSF: how to create a period picker?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'd like to add a period picker on my website but I didn't find any option on PrimeFaces.

The idea is that I'd get a calendar where I can pick two dates and have the period between these two dates selected.

Is there an option to do that ?

Comment: It is possible to make it with jQuery. Primesfaces does not support two dates in calendar. Check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452066/jquery-ui-datepicker-multiple-date-selections

Answer (score 3):

You did not find an option in PrimeFaces but did you check the PrimeFaces issue list for feature requests?

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/2202

Up to 6.1 it is not available and I'm not sure it will be in 6.2. I, unfortunately, do not have the time to create a pull request myself (I'm going to need it in the not too distant future myself)