# datetime calendar : select date range in a single input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is there a javascript datetimepicker that can selects 2 dates in a single input field. Like:
[image]
(Screenshot taken from google-analytics)

Currently we need to use 2 form input fields to select date range.

Is there any free datetimepicker that provides this functionality?

Comment: There are already some questions on SO handling this subject, quick search led me here : http://dubrox.blogspot.be/2010/09/multiple-dates-picker-for-jquery-ui.html
http://sourceforge.net/projects/multidatespickr/ @author dubrox (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/903628/jquery-ui-datepicker-can-it-handle-multiple-dates) Or even more: http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net/

Comment: It can certainly be done with one calendar and two (possibly hidden) inputs. Is that what is desired?

Comment: I want to capture 2 dates using a single datepicker and in a single input field. See @K-Maertens answer below.

Comment: Give this library a try. It doesn't require jQuery and is pretty lightweight: https://github.com/kaore/CibulCalendar

Comment: I would recommend [Date Range Picker for Twitter Bootstrap](https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker/). It does what you need and even it's build on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) it seems to be quite easily convertible to work without it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what you're looking for: https://github.com/dangrossman/bootstrap-daterangepicker